# Java Web Launch Cashes the Second JNLP file runs

Tags: java, java-web-start

I recently updated to Java 7 update 7 from Java 6 update 34. Since then I can not get my web launch application to start up. The second the jnlp file is clicked you see a crash "Java(TM) Web Start Stop working" and here is the crash details.

```
 Problem Event Name:    BEX
  Application Name: javaws.exe
  Application Version:  10.7.2.10
  Application Timestamp:    503d8a47
  Fault Module Name:    javaws.exe
  Fault Module Version: 10.7.2.10
  Fault Module Timestamp:   503d8a47
  Exception Offset: 00011d9c
  Exception Code:   c0000417
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 79a7
  Additional Information 2: 79a788ef5b208f5db755fb6fe2ead642
  Additional Information 3: 6ba7
  Additional Information 4: 6ba7cf2c928ae3198a287be9ff3f435
```

Now web launch was working before I updated. So I'm not sure whats wrong now. I've go through and made sure my cache was cleared. I've unisntalled java and reinstalled it. I also noticed that while looking into this that since java 7 the jnlp urls have to be SSL. Which i wish i knew a way to change this, because once i finish the application the site will require client SSL.

My main dev computer is Windows 7 64 bit and the jre installed is also 64bit.

Here is my JNLP file any see what would be causing it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jnlp
    spec="1.0+"
    codebase="https://192.168.1.1/java/"
    href="webstart.jnlp?k=29&d=Z4UNLF1uzy%2F1MBX99P6dEFdUul%2BKYXds5kyFZ3YJL6RpHy78tKq1vcH67hppjxVqOeeUsOvTDLxDbAFwMUu4dQ%3D%3D">
    <information>
        <title>My App Name</title>
        <vendor>My Company Name</vendor>
        <description>Description</description>
        <description kind="short">Description</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <property name="sun.awt.disableMixing" value="false"/>
        <property name="jnlp.concurrentDownloads" value="15"/>
        <property name="sun.java2d.opengl" value="true"/>
        <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="false"/>
        <jar href="core/Utilities.jar" />
        <jar href="core/DPFP.jar" />
        <jar href="core/SigPad.jar" />
        <jar href="core/Service.jar" />
        <jar href="core/TimeServer.jar" />
        <jar href="core/Marketing.jar" />
        <jar href="core/App.jar" />
        <jar href="core/ElementTest.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/ekitspell.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/DJNativeSwing.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/SigPlus2_57.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/japura.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/ekit.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/RXTXcomm.jar" />
        <jar href="universal/json_simple-1.1.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux">
        <jar href="linux/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="linux/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="linux/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="linux/dpotjni.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac OS">
        <jar href="mac/OS/swt_mac.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac OS X">
        <jar href="mac/OSX/swt_mac.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows 2000" arch="x86">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86/swt_windows_x86.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows 2000" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86_64/swt_windows_x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows XP" arch="x86">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86/swt_windows_x86.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows XP" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86_64/swt_windows_x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows Vista" arch="x86">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86/swt_windows_x86.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows Vista" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86_64/swt_windows_x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows 2003" arch="x86">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86/swt_windows_x86.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows 2003" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86_64/swt_windows_x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows 7">
        <jar href="windows/dpfpenrollment.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpfpverification.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotapi.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/dpotjni.jar" />
        <jar href="windows/x86/swt_windows_x86.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.myapp.Main">
        <argument>k=29</argument>
        <argument>d=Z4UNLF1uzy/1MBX99P6dEFdUul+KYXds5kyFZ3YJL6RpHy78tKq1vcH67hppjxVqOeeUsOvTDLxDbAFwMUu4dQ==</argument>
    </application-desc>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: 1st validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the answer is here:
http://docs.i9technologies.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3113436

Comment: I don't think that solution will work for us. The k & d get variables are required. They are auto login information for the program. The entire jnlp file is actually nothing more then a PHP script that dynamically parses a folder structure looking for jar files to include. As well if the k & d variables are not there the script wont even run. I did it that to help secure the system. Let alone most of those who will be using the program wont on their normal employees having the login information.